# Requests with JS - is this out dated?

Tags: javascript

I am making a basic live chat and was wondering if i have learnt this correctly...

I have my call function like this:

```
function call_data(url,data)
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {              
    AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();              
  } else {                                  
    AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (AJAX) {
  querystring = "?dta="+data;
     AJAX.open("GET", url + querystring, false);                             
     AJAX.send(null);
     return AJAX.responseText;                                         
  } else {
     return false;
  }                                             
}   

function checker(id){
        result = parseInt(call_data('check_chat.php',id)); //check new messages
        if(result){//if new message
        loadchat(id); //load the messages
        } else {
        setTimeout(function() { checker(id); }, 5000); //check for new message every 5 seconds
        }
}
```

Is this the best way to call for new messages periodically ?

Comment: You're using AJAX synchronously, which I wouldn't recommend. If your PHP script gets delayed your javascript will block while it does so.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: [XMLHttpRequest is not necessarily async](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#synchronous-flag), so all XMLHttpRequests are not considered "AJAX" requests.

Comment: So does that mean mine is okay @JoelPurra?

Comment: @JoelPurra But it will still block regardless of naming/terminology

Comment: @LeeTaylor: it was a response to your deleted comment.

Comment: @JoelPurra, yes I realised that the third parameter was false ;-)

Comment: @Dave: it's not the best way to call for new messages periodically. Check out asynchronous requests, as LeeTaylor and JeremyJStarcher have suggested. Also, [jQuery's AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) helps a lot!

Comment: Doing Ajax *manually* is, IMO, outdated, when there are a ton of libraries, some quite small, that handle all the cross-browser BS for you, and clean things up considerably.

Comment: I'm trying to do it library free personally. Just as a learning thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a synchronous call with  `XMLHttpRequest` -- this causes the browser to freeze until data is returned.  `asynchronous` are MUCH nicer and only a touch more complicated.

I'd recommend doing a bit more research yet.

I took a quick look at this link, it might help: http://www.cristiandarie.ro/asp-ajax/Async.html